# prolog royal family grandfather/2 and grandmother/2

Tags: prolog

I am doing a prolog question and need to make a single predicate (a rule) for grandfather/2 and grandmother/2 that uses the pre-existing father/2 mother/2 facts. I have got the rest of it working for example:

```
male(philip).
male(charles).
male(andrew).
male(william).
.....
female(diana).
female(camilla).
female(meghan).
female(kate).
....
married(charles, camilla).
married(harry, meghan).
married(mark, anne).
married(mike, zara).
....
father(philip, charles).
father(philip, andrew).
father(william, george).
father(william, charlotte).
....
mother(elizabeth, charles).
mother(kate, gerge).
mother(anne, zara).
mother(diana, william).
```

I've been stuck on getting the grandfather/2 and grandmother/2 bit to work for a while now, just wondering if anyone can help me, Thanks :).

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: I tried ```grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z),
father(Z, Y).
grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z),
mother(Z, Y).
```

Comment: what problems do you encounter with this?

Comment: when I try querying Prolog with: ```grandfather(philip,X) - to see who Philip is a grandfather to.
grandfather(X,charlotte) - to see who Charlotte's grandfather is.``` I dont get anything back.

Comment: you're missing Luise :)

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the predicate `father(A, B).` is that *`A`* is the father of *`B`*. *`X`* is a grandfather of *`Z`* given there exists a person *`Y`* such that *`X`* is the father of *`Y`* and *`Y`* is a parent of *`Z`*.

It therefore might be better to first implement a predicate `parent/2`:

```
parent(X, Y) :-
    father(X, Y).
parent(X, Y) :-
    mother(X, Y).

grandfather(X, Z) :-
    father(X, Y),
    parent(Y, Z).
```

With the above facts however, you will not get any results, because you did not define enough facts for a grandparent relation.

You thus can add extra facts like:

```
father(philip, charles).
father(philip, andrew).
father(charles, william).
father(charles, harry).
father(william, george).
father(william, charlotte).

mother(elizabeth, charles).
mother(kate, gerge).
mother(anne, zara).
mother(diana, william).
```

This then gives us as `grandfather/2` results:

```
?- grandfather(X, Y).
X = philip,
Y = william ;
X = philip,
Y = harry ;
X = charles,
Y = george ;
X = charles,
Y = charlotte ;
false.
```

Comment: I have all the fathers and mothers defined to their children but it's still saying that they haven't been defined [link]https://prnt.sc/rmkc8c